# Modify url withut changing the code

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to change my current url to a modified one.

Suppose my current url is

```
www.abc.com/xyz/location.htm
```

I want it to change to

```
www.abc.com/location.htm
```

please suggest a suitable way....
Thanks in advance

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Yes ... M using apache server

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Apache servers, I'd suggest using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

In that case you should have something like this in your `.htaccess` -file at the top level of your server root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^abc.com/xyz/(.*)$  <your_root_directory>/$1
```

Comment: here <your_root_directory> refers to where my application is present in tomcat??

Comment: It's the URL to the root of your application, so if you want to remove xyz, it should be enough just to remove the your directory part altogether.  Also I am not sure if you need the host part (^abc.com) either if you use .htaccess at the top of your web application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate...... m not understanding much as m just started using Apache server..

Comment: @neeraj: Your comment above appears to suggest that you may be using "tomcat". Just to clarify, are you using "Apache Webserver" or "Apache Tomcat"? They are 2 very different things.

Comment: My war file is deployed in  apache tomcat....n i m access it using Apache Webserver.
Hence instead of giving localhost:8080 to open the application m using only localhost.